# Next-Auth (Route Handler) how to use NextResponse

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a fetch inside my next-auth and this fetch returns a set-cookie header but because this is called from next-auth the cookie is not passed to browser.
So I want to use NextResponse to "manually" set the cookie. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To set cookies use the 'cookies()' function. See [NextJS cookies](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies).
You can also mutate them with 'NextResponse'. See [NextJS NextResponse](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response)